# C++ string::erase deletes the entire string?

Tags: c++, string, erase

SO here in my function

```
string chopstring(string& tocut, List test[26]){
    string totoken = "";
    while(tocut[0] == ' ' || tocut[0] == 10 || tocut[0] == 13){
        tocut.erase(0);
    }
    int finish = 0;
    finish = tocut.find(" ", 0);
    if (finish == string::npos){
        cout << "NPOS!" << endl;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 26; i++)
        test[i].Print();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < finish; i++){
        totoken += tocut[i];
    }
    string::iterator start = tocut.begin();
    string::iterator end = tocut.begin() + totoken.length();
    tocut.erase(start, end);
    return tokenize(totoken);
}
```

Im having trouble with the string::erase. It deletes the entire string? Any suggestions? Id like to learn the reason too so please explain if you know.

it's being called in another function that stored the returned token in a linked list, then calls this function again untill the string (tocut) is empty. The first line it feeds in is 
"The Time Traveller (for so it will be convenient to speak of him)".
What happens right now is that it takes the first "The", tokenizes it, and does it's thing, but the tocut.erase(start, end), deletes the whole string, and causes the program to crash.

Comment: Could you provide an example call to this function, along with the expected and actual results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do below:

```
    while(tocut[0] == ' ' || tocut[0] == 10 || tocut[0] == 13){
        tocut.erase(0,1);   // see cpp reference. For single argument it takes iterator
    }
```

Comment: @OP : you should also exit from your function when it reaches NPOS as jogojapan has mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

ArunMu is right. But if I am not mistaken, an additional problem is that when the function reaches string::npos it does not end. Instead it continues down to where the call to erase() is made, and erase(start,string::npos) deletes the entire rest of the string indeed.